# Redirect after scrolling the page

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

is it possible to create a redirect only after the page has been scrooled, for example, in the middle and redirects to another page? I tried various solutions and plugins but couldn't find anything that suited me

Comment: Also this is not good for user experience or accessibility to randomly redirect a user as their scrolling, it will confuse screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: You can easily do this by using **jQuery**.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
  } else {
    console.log('test');
  }
});
```

Comment: how do i put it in a WordPress page editor?

Comment: Just put this in the footer.php before the </footer> closing tag

Comment: if I put it in the footer all the pages will have the redirect, I have to do it only for a specific page and above all there must be this redirect after I have reached the middle of the page with the scroll

Comment: You can use the "page id" or is_page function and under that you can put the script.